# redirect all wifi user to specific page in debian

Tags: linux, debian, wifi-hotspot

How can I forward all incoming traffic (http request on port 80 & 443) to a fixed IP address?
I am using raspberry Pi B+ model, tp-link WiFi adapter. I have tried, among others, these two commands:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 0/0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.101:80
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 0/0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.101:443
```

following this tutorial: [pilon tutorial](https://github.com/thgh/pilon)